# Condition in Case of Select/Case statement in classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I've recently been tasked with updating a classic ASP page and have no experience in this language. Is it possible to write a condition into a `Select` statement's `case` like so:

```
Select Case <variable>
Case <value> && <if variable2 == something>
Case <value> || <if variable2 == something else>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This uses comma syntax:

```
Case <value>, variable2 = something else   <--- case satisfies either condition.
```

You cannot build IF statements into the cases.

BTW: VBScript uses "and", "or" and "=", instead of "&&" "||" or "=="

Equal and assignment both use "=" and are context-dependent.

Comment: Worth to mention that classic ASP can be written with JScript as well, having complete JavaScript syntax.